# PHP Class Constants - Public, Private or Protected?

Tags: php, constants

Am I correct in assuming that const properties are automatically public? Is there a way to make them private or protected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the reason to make them hidden? Even though they are public - they are read only.

Comment: Constants are meant to be public, because they are to describe immutable facts about the class, not the state or it. So there's no value in hiding them.

Comment: Might fake them in future versions with `__getStatic`. Generally it's questionable if you need access modifiers at all in scripting languages. (Javascript/Python being way more object-oriented don't need them.)

Comment: Yeah, kind of a dumb question in retrospect. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: I don't think it's dumb question at all; private class constants would be useful: For internal use in the class ... public methods could use them, but outside code shouldn't depend on them ... the API might change.

Comment: well for one, if you wanted to create a database class, it would make sense to declare the host, username, server, db as private constants right?

Comment: In ASP.net if I wanted to store some static information that the class needs but is not needed outside of the class, I'd use private constants stored at the top, easily found and changeable.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Historically, class constants were always publicly accessible as long as the class was loaded and there was no way to change this.

As of PHP 7.1, they remain public by default but [access modifiers may now be applied](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.class-constant-visibility). Here's the example from the release notes:

```php
<?php
class ConstDemo
{
    const PUBLIC_CONST_A = 1;
    public const PUBLIC_CONST_B = 2;
    protected const PROTECTED_CONST = 3;
    private const PRIVATE_CONST = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Class constants should have the option of being private/protected because being public exposes internal details of the class that other classes/code can mistakingly use thinking they are ok to use because they are public.

It would be nice to know that changing a private constant would ONLY affect the class it's defined in. Unfortunately we don't have that option.

Remember back to when you were learning Object Design & Analysis... you give class methods and attributes the most RESTRICTIVE access possible, and later relax them as needed (much harder to go back the other way because other classes/code start using them which would then break other code).

WORKAROUND

Best bet is to just create a private or protected variable and upper-case it to show it's a constant. You could always create a class called constant($value_to_be_constant) that implements the correct magic methods / spl interfaces to prevent it from being changed.

Answer (score 6):

*I am aware this question is 6 years old*

Php 7.1 (currently RC1) allows to specify visibility on class constants.

```
class Token {
        // Constants default to public
        const PUBLIC_CONST = 0;

        // Constants then also can have a defined visibility
        private const PRIVATE_CONST = 0;
        protected const PROTECTED_CONST = 0;
        public const PUBLIC_CONST_TWO = 0;

        //Constants can only have one visibility declaration list
        private const FOO = 1, BAR = 2;
}
```

## Additional info

- [RFC on class const visibility](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_const_visibility)
- [Blog post on Class Constant Visibility](https://blog.pascal-martin.fr/post/php71-en-syntax-and-consistency.html)

Answer (score 3):

As of **php7.1**, you can define your class constants with **access modifiers** (`public`, `private` or `protected`). Have a look at the following example:

```
<?php
class superheroes{
    public const kal_el = 'Superman';
    protected const bruce_wayne = 'Batman'; # works php7.1 onwards
    private const anthony_stark = 'Iron Man'; # works php7.1 onwards

    public static function show_remaining(){
        echo self::bruce_wayne, '<br />';
        echo self::anthony_stark, '<br />';
    }
}
echo superheroes::kal_el, '<br />';
superheroes::show_remaining();
```

Credits: http://dwellupper.io/post/48/defining-class-constants-in-php