# why did I get this error?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Class Constants - Public, Private or Protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505165/php-class-constants-public-private-or-protected)

Parse error: **syntax error,** unexpected T_CONST, expecting T_VARIABLE in

code -

```
<?php
    // Data Transfer Object
        class DTO {
            private const ADMINSLATOR_ID = 'Adminslator';
            private const ADMINSLATOR_PASSWORD = 'Secret';

            function __construct(){
                echo "I am the DTO Object";
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Constants are always public. You can't have private ones.

Comment: Little bit late but as of PHP 7.1 constants can be private.

Answer (score 9):

Because class constants don't have a visibility in PHP. They are always static and callable from outside (i.e. public).
Just remove the `private` before.

Comment: “As of PHP 7.1.0 visibility modifiers are allowed for class constants.“ – http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
// Data Transfer Object
    class DTO {
        private static $ADMINSLATOR_ID = 'Adminslator';
        private static $ADMINSLATOR_PASSWORD = 'Secret';

        function __construct(){
            echo "I am the DTO Object";
        }
    }
?>
```

I added the $ sign to your variables and replaced const with static.

Comment: Na, that would't work either.

Answer (score 0):

class constants cannot be private in php.
if you need some private variable, maybe use private static $ADMINSLATOR_ID etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `private` keyword has placed just before the `const` keyword; because class constants can not be private.